# InvokeWebRequest - Continue reading file after 4XX/5XX error

Tags: powershell

I am implementing sort of a heartbeat, need to send a GET request to a list of URLs.

I am reading URLs from a .txt, InvokeWebRequest causes my script to terminate if the HTTP Status code is not 200. How can I go around this so my script continues reading/processing the remaining lines in the file?

Already tried -ErrorAction ContinueSilently

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($filePath)

Try {
        while ($null -ne ($line = $reader.ReadLine())) {
            Write-Host -foregroundcolor "YELLOW" "Processing URL: $line"
            Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri $line -DisableKeepAlive      -TimeoutSec 5  | Select-Object StatusCode,StatusDescription | Format-List

}
```

}

```
Catch {
    $exceptionString = $_.Exception.ToString()
    If($exceptionString -match '404') { Write-Host "FCK" }
```

}

```
Finally {
    $reader.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You could either move the try/catch block to include only the call to the web service method OR add another try/catch block within the current one, but again, just for the line that calls the web service method.

For example,

try
{
    Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri $line -DisableKeepAlive      -TimeoutSec 5  | Select-Object StatusCode,StatusDescription | Format-List
}
catch
{
    # could output specific or general error message, but otherwise ignore
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Clearing the mess I had within the Try block was the solution.